# Java GridBagLayout clumping together in one line

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Im using `GridBagLayout` to align `JButtons`, `JLabels`, and `JTextFields` into a login form. But sometimes all the objects get crammed into one line. (not allways, it happens randomly but too often to ignore).

this is how I'm aligning the objects

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class ManagerMain {
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("this is a frame");
    private JLabel loginNameLB = new JLabel("username:");
    private JLabel loginPasswordLB = new JLabel("password:");
    private JTextField loginName = new JTextField();
    private JPasswordField loginPassword = new JPasswordField();
    private JButton loginBTN = new JButton("Login");
    private JButton loginCreateBTN = new JButton("Create An Account");
    private Container login = new Container();
    //login is a container
    public ManagerMain() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        login.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 15, 15);
        gbc1.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc1.weightx = 1.0;
        //user name label
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc1.gridheight = 1;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        login.add(loginNameLB, gbc1);
        //user name text field
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc1.gridheight = 1;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        login.add(loginName, gbc1);
        //password label
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc1.gridheight = 1;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        login.add(loginPasswordLB, gbc1);
        //password text field
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc1.gridheight = 1;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        login.add(loginPassword, gbc1);
        //login button
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 2;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc1.gridheight = 1;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        login.add(loginBTN, gbc1);
        //create account button
        gbc1.gridx = 2;
        gbc1.gridy = 2;
        gbc1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc1.gridheight = 1;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        login.add(loginCreateBTN, gbc1);
        frame.add(login, BorderLayout.CENTER);//add container to frame
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Image of what it looks like / what it should look like is bellow

[image: Screenshot 1]

sometimes it does this also:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Get rid of the gridwidth and gridheight to start with

Comment: Looks like the layout has been rest to FlowLayout

Comment: This is why I avoid Swing layout managers (just look at all that code). I would suggest you use a third-party library like MigLayout. I realise this doesn't answer your question and you might not want to add dependencies to your project, but it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @dramzy can you link me to a good tutorial/project example using `MigLayout`?

Comment: It's all on their [site](http://www.miglayout.com): here is the [quick start guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf) and the [white paper](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html)

Comment: I turned out at [Java GridBagLayout not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088675/java-gridbaglayout-not-working) that `GridBagLayout` doesn't always work as expected. Maybe `GroupLayout` or [JGoodies FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) are other options.

Comment: @dramzy you're gonna regret it once you start deploying applications. Absolute layout (null layout, as you'd call it) may render different results on different platforms. It's best allow LayoutManagers to configure the layout

Comment: @VinceEmigh MigLayout IS a layout manager, it is not the same as using an absolute layout. It is just a simpler third-party layout manager with simpler constraints. I have used it for various projects and tested it on Mac OS, Windows, and some linux distros.

Comment: Setting the GridBagConstraints, specifically gridy, should take care of putting the components on different lines. In fact, when I run this code myself it works as it should (per the above image).

Answer (score 3):

> it happens randomly but too often to ignore. Any suggestions?

1. You should invoke `setVisible(...)` AFTER all the components have been added to the frame.
2. You should invoke `pack()` BEFORE setVisible()..
3. Make sure the GUI components are created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)